# About behaviour of / by vector in Julia

Tags: vector, julia, division, broadcast

`3/[2;2]` gives

```
1×2 LinearAlgebra.Transpose{Float64,Array{Float64,1}}:
 0.75  0.75
```

while `3 ./[2;2]` gives

```
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.5
 1.5
```

The second one is easy to comprehend. It broadcasts `3` and performs element wise division. But what is the reasoning behind having the first operation behave as it did? I assume it took the sum of the vector, which was 2x1, performed division of 3 by 4 and broadcast it to a 1x2 transposed vector. I can accept taking the sum of the vector to perform division, but why the transpose? Or why not just return a scalar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply gives the right hand side operand's pseudo-inverse.

```
julia> ?/
...  
Right division operator: multiplication of x by the inverse of y on the right.
```

Although it seems surprising at first sight, it is actually the natural behavior. A rowvector*columnvector gives a scalar and hence a scalar divided by a column vector should give a row vector, which is the case. Note that `RowVector` has been removed in 1.0 and what you get is actually a row vector represented with `Transpose`.

You can write `@less 1 / [2;2]` to see what actually happens.

Also take a look at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/25431) to understand the behaviour a bit more and [this discourse topic](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/scalar-divided-by-range-or-array/8196/5) for some use cases.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is calculating the [pseudoinverse of the vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Vectors) and then multiplying by 3.

Using `@which 3/[2;2]` and so on to see what actually happens, I found that it is eventually calling the following method in `stdlib/LinearAlgebra/generic.jl`:

```
function _vectorpinv(dualfn::Tf, v::AbstractVector{Tv}, tol) where {Tv,Tf}
    res = dualfn(similar(v, typeof(zero(Tv) / (abs2(one(Tv)) + abs2(one(Tv))))))
    den = sum(abs2, v)
    # as tol is the threshold relative to the maximum singular value, for a vector with
    # single singular value σ=√den, σ ≦ tol*σ is equivalent to den=0 ∨ tol≥1
    if iszero(den) || tol >= one(tol)
        fill!(res, zero(eltype(res)))
    else
        res .= dualfn(v) ./ den
    end
    return res
end
```

which in the given case effectively becomes `transpose([2;2])/sum(abs2, [2;2])` which is the pseudoinverse.

However, this is a bit above my head. So someone more qualified might prove me wrong.